# FastAPI key in both header and URL

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, fastapi

I have a FastAPI-based Python3 API which needs authentification. I can request API key in the body or as a part of URL using Depends like described [here](https://itsjoshcampos.codes/fast-api-api-key-authorization). Is there a way to accept it from *either* source?

The expected behavoiur is like this: if API key is available in `x-api-key` header, return whatever the endpoint is supposed to return. Else, look in URL for `?api_key=mysecretkey` value. If it is found there and it is valid, proceed to the endpoint; otherwise, return 401 or 403.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generally use the dependency system for FastAPI to compose dependencies and move the logic into smaller, composable dependencies.

To accept an api key both as a query parameter and a header, create a dependency that allows either, both being optional, then make sure at least one is present (and decide which one you want to give precedence to if both is present):

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Query, Header
from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException
from typing import Annotated, Optional

app = FastAPI()

users = {
    'random_token': {'id': 1}
}



def token_from_header_or_qs(api_key: str | None = Query(None), x_api_key: str | None = Header(None)) -> str:
    token = api_key or x_api_key
    
    if not token:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400)
        
    return token
    

def get_current_user(token: Annotated[str, Depends(token_from_header_or_qs)]):
    user = users.get(token)
    
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401)
        
    return user
    
    
@app.get("/")
def protected_endpoint(user: Annotated[dict, Depends(get_current_user)]):
    return user
```

The `token_from_header_or_qs` function allows the token from either source, while the `get_current_user` function is only concerned about validating the token and fetching the user. The only thing the controller function needs to care about is getting a valid user (you can also register these as dependencies on an APIRouter or on the FastAPI instance itself if you want them to be present for all, or a group of, routes.

Comment: Thanks, this works. In fact, a single function that takes a token from either header or qs, and then processes it (throwing HTTPException if something is bad) should be enough, if you do not need granular access control

Comment: You'd implement the granular access control as a secondary dependency, externally from authenticating the user - something like `user: .. Depends(get_user_with_group('admin'))`, where the `get_user_with_group` dependency returns a function that validates against the given group.